# SQL: Trying to find if gift was given year following first gift year

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SSMS version 18.9.2 and I'm trying to get a list IDs who gave a gift the year following the year after their FIRST gift date. Meaning if their first gift was in 2019 and they gave a gift in 2020 then row count = 1, then the next person's first gift also was in 2019, but did NOT give a gift in 2020, then row count would remain 1 even though we have reviewed a total of two people. Hope that makes since.

Using a sample data as this, I would expect my row count to be 1; returning only ID 2

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3/8/1981 |
| 1 | 2/11/1988 |
| 1 | 2/15/1995 |
| 2 | 2/22/1982 |
| 2 | 2/24/1983 |
| 2 | 3/15/1983 |
| 2 | 2/17/1984 |
| 3 | 2/16/1984 |
| 3 | 3/13/1984 |
| 3 | 6/13/1986 |
| 4 | 2/2/1983 |
| 4 | 3/11/1985 |
| 4 | 3/21/1986 |

This is the closest I've gotten to work. Notice the two different `HAVING`s where as first works but the second fails which the second is how it needs to work:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT 
     gifts1.giftid, 
     YEAR(gifts2.gifteffdat) AS 'MINYR',  
     YEAR(MIN(gifts1.gifteffdat)) AS 'MINYR+1' 
 FROM 
     gifts AS gifts1 
 INNER JOIN 
     gifts AS gifts2 ON gifts1.giftid = gifts2.giftid
                     AND DATEDIFF(year, gifts2.gifteffdat, gifts1.gifteffdat) = 1
 GROUP BY 
     gifts1.giftid, gifts1.gifteffdat, gifts2.gifteffdat
 -- THIS HAVING WORKS
 HAVING 
     (YEAR(gifts2.gifteffdat) = 1982)
 -- THIS HAVING DOESNT WORK
 -- HAVING YEAR(gifts2.gifteffdat) = YEAR(MIN(gifts1.gifteffdat)) +1
```

I appreciate any help! Thank you!

Comment: `HAVING` should only be applied to aggregated expressions - `SUM`, `COUNT`, `AVG` and so forth. In your case, you should use `WHERE` instead - before the `GROUP BY` (this only works for the "working" `HAVING` in your case)

Comment: Your requirement is unclear to me. Please include the expected result based on that sample data

Comment: Squirrel - For the output I'm trying to get a list IDs. Above is of course just a small sample set. However in the real set there are nearly 90,000 unique ID's and hundreds of thousands of gifts (gifteffdat) to query on.

Comment: marc_s - I tried to use WHERE but couldn't get it work correctly. I was thinking the 'non-working' HAVING would be the closest thing that I needed. I concur that HAVING is for aggregated expressions and that WHERE is will not work with aggregated expressions.

Comment: I figured it out... I had take a different approach with the HAVING. This is what ended up working

 HAVING YEAR(MIN(gifts.gifteffdat)) + 1 = (SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(gifts2.gifteffdat) FROM [<database>].[dbo].[gifts] gifts2 ORDER BY YEAR(gifts2.gifteffdat) OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY)